# Intuition behind portfolio weights with lower RMSE but higher variance

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory

I have recently encountered a phenomena in portfolio optimization that has baffled me for days. I was experimenting with different ways of transforming a covariance matrix to get a stable minimum variance portfolio out-of-sample. To do this, I employed this methodology:

1. Set a portfolio holding period of 21 days.
2. Determine range of lookback windows, where the minimum lookback window is 21 days.
3. For each lookback window, randomly sample a portfolio of 100 assets.
4. Calculate both the sample covariance matrix and the "oracle" covariance matrix (covariance matrix in the holding period).
5. Apply transforming method to the sample covariance matrix to get the transformed covariance matrix.
6. Feed the oracle and transformed covariance matrix into a minimum variance portfolio optimizer to obtain weights.
7. Repeat 1000 times for each lookback window.
8. Verify that the "oracle" weights indeed produce the minimum variance portfolio on average, and benchmark weights produced by the different transformation schemes against the "oracle" weights by calculating their RMSE.

Intuitively, a lower RMSE should lead to a lower out-of-sample variance (in the holding period). But I have found that not to be true for non-linear shrinkage. Weirdly enough, non-linear shrinkage consistently produces portfolio weights with lower RMSE (across all lookback periods) but higher variance out-of-sample. Not sure why that is the case, and I'm hoping you guys can give some insights!

Portfolio constraints were:

- long-only
- leverage set at 1